# JSHint: Multiple Indents?

Tags: javascript, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I'm using D3 in my project.  I'd love to enforce a specific indentation pattern, but due to the multiple chaining I'd like to organize my code using multiple instances of indentation.  JSHint throws an error when I have something like this:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select(location).append('svg')
    .attr()
    .attr();

    var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append('g') // throws error here
        .attr()
        .call();
```

Is there any possible way I can enforce 4 indents, but ignore multiple indentations in .jshintrc?  i.e. `var AxisGroup` stems from `svgContainer`, would like the nesting without warnings from JSHint.

Comment: What's version of JSHint do you use?

Comment: I'm using it in Grunt and I'm very new with Grunt. "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.9.2",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through research I've definitively found that "white" is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

It turns out I was using grunt's `grunt-contrib-jshint` at an older version before version 2.5.0 where JSHint allows multiple indentation.

Changing the `package.json` I had for grunt to `"grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",` fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can try set this in your `.jshintrc`:

```
"indent": 4,
"white": false
```

Also, please check out [JSHint Docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/).
And it looks like in last version, devs solved issue with indent warnings: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.0

> indent no longer provides warnings about indentation levels

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like "white" is deprecated.  Apparently Grunt is using 2.5.0 as well https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint#release-history.